# Earthquakes in another country Assume that in an other country the probability that during a year at least one earthquake happens is 0,3...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Earthquakes in another country
Assume that in an other country the probability that during a year at least one
earthquake happens is  0,3 . What is the probability that during 5 years the number
of earthquakes is at least 3? Note: We need to apply "Poisson Distribution" for solving this problem.

Hi guys. I solved this problem with help of simple proportion. I said that if during 1 year probability is 0.3 , then during 5 is X and found X which is 1,5
. Thus probability is 1,5 . I just want to make sure that the result is right. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How could the probability be greater than $1$?

Comment: It's certainly wrong. Probabilities must be between 0 and 1

Comment: Note: as stated the problem really can't be solved.  We don't even have enough information to compute the probability that there are at least $3$ earthquakes in a single year.

Comment: @lulu that's right

Comment: Hint: Let $X$ be the number of earthquakes that happen in 5 years. Then,
$P\{X\geq 3\}=1-P\{X<3\}$.

Comment: Well, as the problem can't be solved as stated, perhaps you want to modify it in some way, no?  For example, it would make sense to ask "given $5$ years, what is the probability that there are earthquakes in at least $3$  of the years?"  But it's your question...it really doesn't make sense for other people to try to guess what you might mean.

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna modify

Comment: Assume that in a certain country the average number of earthquakes during a year
is 1,6 . What is the probability that during a year the number of earthquakes is at
most 2? What is the probability that during 3 years the number of earthquakes
is at most 2? How many earthquakes are the most probable during a year, and
during 3 years? Can we get some info from here?

Comment: Not really.  There are many distributions that would give us that average.

Comment: I didn't mention that we had to solve this question with help of Poission Distribution.

Comment: Well, obviously, knowing the underlying distribution would make a big difference.  I suggest rewriting your question to include all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Poisson distribution, the expected number in five years is $1.5$.  That is the $\lambda$ parameter in the distribution, so the probability of $n$ earthquakes in $5$ years is 
$$P(n)=\frac {1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{n!}$$Now compute the probability of $0$ to $2$ earthquakes and subtract from $1$ to get the chance of at least $3$ earthquakes.